# Ldap Integration with Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am Using Liferay 6.1CE.

I can able to connect ldap server to my portal. Users are get imported, also authentication is done.

But when i add a user in AD,it will not imported to portal by the time.It will added only after restart the server(Import on startup is working).

I have never seen a option in liferay to enable this.

so i set a ldap.import.interval=360 in portal-ext.properties.But no change.
 What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about always importing all users to Liferay: They will be imported individually at latest when they try to log in - typically you don't need them before that, and you want them to be up to date at exactly that time.

Comment: authentication failure when am trying to access with the newly created user in AD